# render MyGlobalNavigationFixup conditionally

Tags: 2010, navigation, delegate-control

I have created a single GlobalNavigation delegate control that displays different markup based on a condition (code below shows only the negative condition, an over simplified version).  The MyGlobalNavigationFixup behavior happens even when the tag shouldn't render.

That is, when this code executes, MyGlobalNavigationFixup effects the page.  Because it is inside a negative condition, I would not expect it to affect the page.

What I'm trying to create is a single delegate control that uses the MyGlobalNavigationFixup only in certain situations.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 

<% if (false) { %>
    <SPSWC:MyGlobalNavigationFixup ID="globalnav" runat="server"/>
<% } %>
```

How can I render/use/apply MyGlobalNavigationFixup based on a condition?